# Flutter and Firebase Authentication: How to login anonymously only once per user/IP address

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've set up Firebase Authentication on Flutter web with only an ANONYMOUS sign-in button available.

When I close the web app, rerun the program, and sign in anonymously again, a new user ID is generated.

Is there a way for me to save the user's ID and data, so that when they login again, even anonymously, none of their stuff is lost?

Comment: Hate to be captain obvious, but if you are retaining user's info why not ask them to login with email ?

Comment: "When I close the web app, rerun the program, and sign in anonymously again, a new user ID is generated." On most environments this should already be the default behavior, as Firebase persists the (anonymous or otherwise) credentials in local storage. Does this happen on all systems? Or is it on a specific browser (say Safari)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#anonymous-sign-in) it has been stated as :

> If no previous anonymous account on the platform (for your specific application) has been created, when signing in anonymously Firebase will create a new
> unique user which will be persisted across app restarts/page reloads. If the user signs-out and re authenticates anonymously again, they will be signed-in with the previously created account.

One PR has been created to improve the document on [github](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/4336) as when you sign out from an anonymous account, that account's UID is lost and cannot be retrieved, for more information you can refer to the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65158552/15774176).
You can also refer to the [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/dive-into-firebase-auth-on-flutter-phone-and-anonymous-authentication-6ce4f17eb2a8)  and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBJoY4VjECo) which dives into Firebase auth on Flutter.